# What would be the cost for one to mine one of his own block?

Tags: mining, security, solo-mining

Smart contract built countermeasures against flash loan attacks. But some of them are just requiring the money to come from an eoa and thus are at risk from peoples who own the funds for themselves.

There are more and more peoples with large amounts of stolen money. I’m meaning peoples ready to steal funds. And indeed, as far I understand (correct me if I’m wrong). [Rari Capital was hacked using the stolen money from Value Defi](https://www.rekt.news/rari-capital-rekt/), though it didn’t require what I was thinking.

The result is now many projects are protected from attacks using a large amount of funds within a single transaction but not within a single block.
Of course, there are FlashBot bundles for performing those attacks, but this can’t be considered unsafe because a miner is free to strip transactions from the bundle if is accepting to mine the bundle for free. This means transaction ordering isn’t warranted.

So if an attacker wants to perform an attack using large amounts of funds and several transactions, he has to mine his own blocks.

Currently, we can say that getting the block reward (2 Ethers) through a mining pool roughly costs 2 Ethers of electricity which can be distributed from a share of several blocks.
But being able to select which transactions to include can’t be done through a mining pool. Although this is less requiring than a 50% attack, it requires enough hash power for being able to create a block within the timeframe of a year or even a month.
**What would be the cost of mining such blocks in that case**? Is it possible to rent such hashpower without proper aml/kyc and if yes, would it be cheaper?

Comment: Hi there. What do you mean when you say that a miner is free to strip transactions from a Flashbot bundle?

Comment: Also, are you asking how much it would cost to mine a block over a period of a month or year?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks I m meaning he technically can. And then I m interested in both (year and month).

Comment: I don't think a miner can do that. The whole point is that the final transaction in the bundle is the one in which the miner gets paid. He can't just include this one transaction in the bundle because, a) there will be missing nonce values for the transaction(s) he strips out, b) often the preceding transactions make state changes that mean the final payment transaction would be invalid.

Comment: With regards to your mining question: this can't happen, as any block you mine must be based on the previous block (because you must include the previous block's header hash in the block you're mining). So in effect, you have 13 seconds to mine a block (the current block time) - you can't spread it out over longer periods such as months or years.

Comment: (It's possible I've misunderstood what you were asking with your mining question.)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks yes, this is what I m saying. A miner can strip the tail of a transaction if he accept to not be paid which can happens if large amounts are at play. And regarding the question, **you don t understand as I m talking about the cost of the amount of hash power required for finding a block (in terms of luck) within a year or a month** without using a mining pool.

Comment: Okay, I understand now :-) So the probability of mining a block within a certain time frame (e.g. month or year) and how much it would cost in terms of rented hash power. And the reason to do this would be to solo mine a block to bypass the protections in place for flash loan attacks.  Good question :-) +1

Comment: @RichardHorrocks may you retract the close vote then please?

Comment: Hmm, it's not me who has voted to close. It's been flagged as "opinion-based" - I'm not sure why, because to me it seems there should be an objective answer.